# Microsoft IME disabled while in application

Tags: c++, qt, input, globalization, ime

We need our application to be able to accept languages such as Korean/Japanese etc. as input.

However, if I have my Keyboard language set to Korean then in the bottom right of the task bar I get this:

[image: IME disabled]

and if I try to input anything, It's just regular english characters.

In any other windows application (including stack overflow) I can input these characters (ex ㅔㄹㅎ), and this is what the taskbar looks like:

[image]

I'm using Qt and C++, is there any way I can get the same behaviour as any other application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are using custom text edits rendered with OpenGL/DirectX. On the Gl/Dx widget I needed to add `setAttribute(Qt::WA_InputMethodEnabled);` in order to enable the IME.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the [default locale](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlocale.html#setDefault) of your Qt application to the language you are targeting.

```
QLocate::setDefault(QLocale("ko_KR"));
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't help. I even set my OS language to Korean and still no luck. We are using a QTranslator in our app if that's important.

Comment: Do you think perhaps it might have something to do with `Qt::WA_InputMethodEnabled`? http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#WidgetAttribute-enum

Comment: It seems you got it! nice! I'll take note of it too.